# How to truncate/clip the div in the shape of the text lying under it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to truncate the div in the shape of the text and not truncate the text inside the div. So when the div gets truncated the part of the text which lies below it becomes white from black. Is there any property to give the div the shape of text lying under it? Or is there any other solution that can give the same result?
My code is below:

```css
body{
 background:green;
 color:#000;
 text-align:center;
 padding:30px; 
 font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
 font-size:25px;
}
#wrap{position:relative;}
#text{
 position:absolute;
}
#slider{
 position:absolute;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 border-radius:100%;
 background:white;
 /*visibility:hidden;*/
 text-overflow:clip;
 
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/>
 <div id="wrap"> 
  <div id="text">Text lying below the div!</div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If your question isn't already answered, it would be great to improve the quality of your question. It's not 100% clear what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking [for this effect](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnimatedKnockoutLetters/). Not the animmation one, the text-background clip thing. It has a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/animated-knockout-letters/) to create that effect.
There is also a tutorial how to do this [cross browser](http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html). [Another way to do it](http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/)

Comment: But this tutorial has an image behind it which the text clips...is there a way to clip a div that is behind the text?

Comment: I am not sure you can clip a div in the shape of the text. That was the closest thing i knew to what you wanted. What will the div contain?

Comment: Actually the div will have a different color from the text probably a gradient.And with this clipped div placed behind the text i'm gonna apply animation to move it continuously across the text from starting of text till the end and back again.

Comment: you can use the svg (you can do gradients there) and use the backgroud-position css property to animate the movement